# SQL Listing only unique values with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

let me start off by saying Yes this is a homework question.

It seems so simple but I can't get it to work. I am just starting sub-queries and I'm guessing that's what my teacher wants here.

here's the question

```
5.  Write a SELECT statement that returns the name and discount percent 
    of each product that has a unique discount percent. In other words,
    don’t include products that have the same discount percent as another
    product.
     -Sort the results by the ProductName column.
```

Here's what I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.ProductName, p1.DiscountPercent
FROM Products AS p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT p2.ProductName, p2.DiscountPercent
     FROM Products AS p2
     WHERE p1.DiscountPercent <> p2.DiscountPercent)
ORDER BY ProductName;
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated - thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's quite similar to yours, but with `not in` you assure that the discount is not present in another product.

```
SELECT p1.ProductName, p1.DiscountPercent
FROM Products AS p1
WHERE p1.DiscountPercent NOT IN
    (SELECT p2.DiscountPercent
     FROM Products AS p2
     WHERE p1.ProductName <> p2.ProductName)
ORDER BY ProductName
```

Answer (score 2):

When checking for uniqueness using `COUNT()` makes it simple, you can either use it in a `HAVING` clause or select it outright.

```
SELECT a.ProductName, a.DiscountPercent
FROM Products a
JOIN (SELECT DiscountPercent, COUNT(DiscountPercent) AS CT
      FROM Products
      GROUP BY DiscountPercent
     )b
 ON a.DiscountPercent = b.DiscountPercent
WHERE b.CT = 1
```

Or:

```
SELECT a.ProductName, a.DiscountPercent
FROM Products a
JOIN (SELECT DiscountPercent
      FROM Products
      GROUP BY DiscountPercent
      HAVING COUNT(DiscountPercent) = 1
     )b
 ON a.DiscountPercent = b.DiscountPercent
```

Comment: +1 It would be useful to explain how it works and why the original query did not.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to solve this with a subquery, you want to find products for which `NOT EXISTS` another product with an *equal*(`=`) discountPercent, not *different* (`<>`). Using a `<>` in that `NOT EXISTS` clause would return results only if all discountPercents in the table had the same value (there doesn't exist any other product with a different discount --> all discounts are the same)

And take into account that you'll need to add a condition to make sure the subquery isn't finding a match for the same row executing it (i.e. `p1` is not the same row as `p2`)

For instance, if `productName` is enough to identify a `product`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.ProductName, p1.DiscountPercent
FROM Products AS p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT p2.ProductName, p2.DiscountPercent
     FROM Products AS p2
     WHERE p1.DiscountPercent = p2.DiscountPercent
           AND p1.ProductName <> p2.ProductName)
ORDER BY ProductName;
```

Comment: Glad to help, specially if it helped you understand the reasons :-)

Answer (score 0):

## try this query in mysql

```
select ProductName, DiscountPercent
from product
where DiscountPercent in (select DiscountPercent from product
                                 group by DiscountPercent
                                 having count(DiscountPercent)=1)
```